# Two Heroku Apps for the Same Project?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I currently have a django project deployed on Heroku, but I would like to deploy another dummy Heroku app for testing purposes. The idea is that I can make changes to the dummy Heroku account on a git branch, see how it works live, and then merge and push to my actual Heroku project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

Just add another remote on git to the repository to your production heroku git address.

`git remote add htest your_test_app_heroku.git`

`git remote add heroku your_actual_app_heroku.git`

Comment: Ah, yes this works, sorry i realized this a few minutes after I posted this question D: